# Create R code to re-create a data.frame or tibble that I have in memory

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I am trying to generate some R code that creates a data.frame (or tibble). E.g. like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
example_data <- tibble(`Letter number`=1:10, Letter=letters[1:10])
```

I.e. without creating a .csv or .rds file that gets loaded. This is for some training material (a standalone html file created using R markdown), from which people can just copy and paste some code to their R editor/RStudio session. I want to provide a small example dataset to use in exercises.

Let's say I have created the dataset I want on my computer (e.g. reading tables from a pdf using tabulizer, various processing etc.) and now want to create code like the one above in order to be able to copy & paste this code into the .Rmd for generating the html file. Is there something like

```
create_code_to_generate_tibble( example_data )
```

that would output the first code chunk (minus the library loading)?

Comment: Please see the output of `dput(example_data)`

Comment: Thanks dput does indeed come very close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
example_data = structure(list(`Letter number` = 1:10, Letter = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))


> example_data
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   `Letter number` Letter
             <int> <chr> 
 1               1 a     
 2               2 b     
 3               3 c     
 4               4 d     
 5               5 e     
 6               6 f     
 7               7 g     
 8               8 h     
 9               9 i     
10              10 j
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were after a more automated way, however it would be possible to generate a manually-created data frame and populate like:

```
# collection of months (initially empty)
months <- data.frame(
  start_date = character(),
  label = character(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# manually add months with start date, and label
# generate these lines from CSV or Excel for example
months[1L, ] <- c("1/Aug/2022", "August 2022")
months[2L, ] <- c("1/Sep/2022", "September 2022")
months[3L, ] <- c("1/Oct/2022", "October 2022")
months[4L, ] <- c("1/Nov/2022", "November 2022")
```

I find working in rows like this fairly linear & easy to explain.